# How can I fix `undefined method `railtie_namespace'` error when running `rails generate` on the engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The problem is as follows:

```sh
# 1) Create full engine `myengine` with Rails 4.2.10
rails _4.2.10_ plugin new myengine --full

# 2) Try to rails generate 
$ bin/rails g
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>': 
  undefined method `railtie_namespace' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when you are symlinking the engine directory and reach there through the link as follows:

```sh
cd path/to/somewhere
rails _4.2.10_ plugin new myengine --full
ln -s path/to/somewhere/myengine ~/favorite/myengine

cd ~/favorite/myengine

./bin/rails g
```

If you did so, you would run into the error. To fix the problem, change some lines at the top of `bin/rails` as follows:

```rb
# from 
ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib/myengine/engine', __FILE__)

# to
require 'pathname'
ENGINE_ROOT = Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath + '../..'
ENGINE_PATH = ENGINE_ROOT + 'lib/myengine/engine'
```

See the implementation of `::Rails::Engine.find` about why the patch works.